# Simple FTP Client authentication?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, authentication, ftp

I have written a simle FTP Client-Server code using WinSocks. But I am confused in "How to use a simple Username-Password Authentication" ? I have gone through the Authentication links given in MSDN but that made me more confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FTP authentication process is done with the `USER` and `PASS` commands:

```
Command:    USER AbhineetK7
Response:    331 Password required for AbhineetK7.
Command:    PASS **********
Response:    230 Hello!
```

You can find more details [here](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_FTPControlConnectionEstablishmentUserAuthenticatio-2.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I was wondering if there are any WinAPIs for doing so. Its like, when I am connected with the server, the "Username:" string appears on the client Command and after entering the username and hitting Enter, it will ask for the "Password:". Thanks for helping me again. That link was really beneficial.

Comment: There is an OS built in method if you're using the OS built in FTP library (WinInet, etc). As you've rolled your own FTP client, you will need to do your own authentication.

Comment: Yeah, thats correct but could you point to give me some links towards some codes with the Winsock and authentication. Or can you provide some sample here.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you are looking for something like this:
[FTP Winapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As you can see that URL contains full description with examples about FTP connection between Client and Server, with Username-Password Authentication.

Comment: For usernames and passwords, refer to the [InternetConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: Guys, I am already using WinSock APIs like socket,connect,bind,listen,etc.. Moving to FTPWinapi or InternetConnect will make me to change my whole source code.